# Promise keeps pending

Tags: promise

I am trying to combine fetch API and promises

When I do this, everything works

```
queryAPI(currency, cryptocurrency){
    const url = fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => console.log(data));

}
```

However, when I try to store it in a variable, the promise keeps pending

```
queryAPI(currency, cryptocurrency){
    const url = fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')

        .then(response => {
            const user = response.json()
            console.log(user);
        });

}
```

1) What am I doing wrong?

2) Is there any way I can get the value of the "user" outside of the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.json` method also returns a promise. You have to call `.then` once again to get the final result:

```
queryAPI(currency, cryptocurrency){
    const url = fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => console.log(user))

}
```

so you could return the chained `.then`s from the `queryAPI` method and use it in the rest of your code:

```
const queryAPI = (currency, cryptocurrency) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, rej) => {
        return fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => resolve({user: data, currency: 'EUR'}))
            .catch(e => rej(e))
    });
};

queryAPI('EU', 'bitcoin').then(data => {
   console.log(data.user);
   console.log(data.currency)
});
```